# Display a dropdown in a dynamic div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an address `div` which contains 3 elements: address(text area), city(dropdown), locality(dropdown).
We have a <kbd>+</kbd> button a add the same div below existing which gets created dynamically. Now in the dynamic div, how can I call database values in the city dropdown and locality is dependent dropdown on city?
While working on this, I am able to create a new Address(text area) but not dropdown so can anyone help me here?
[image]

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;
$("#addButton").click(function () {
        if (counter > 100) {
            alert("Only 100 Address allowed");
            return false;
        }


    var elems = '<div class="col-lg-5"  id="Address' + counter + '">'+
          '<textarea class="form-control" name="alt_address[]" rows="3" placeholder="Address' + (counter+1) + '" /></div>' + 
          '<div class="col-lg-1 form-group">'+
          '<button type="button" class="removebtn" id="removeButton' + counter + '">' +
          '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>' +
          '</div><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>' +
          '<div class="col-lg-3 form-group" id="city' + counter +'"></div><div class="col-lg-3 form-group" id="locality' + counter  +'"></div><div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6"></div>';


        counter++;
        return false;



                });

                $(document).on('click','.removebtn',function () {

                if(counter==0){
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#Address" + counter).remove();
    $("#removeButton" + counter).remove();


});
```

});

HTML:

```
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="addButton">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                 </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6">
            </div>

               <div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
                <select name="city_name" id="city_name" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select city</option>
        <?php
        $sql="select * from city";

                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))

            {

                   echo "<option value='$row[city_id]'>$row[city_name]</option>";
                     }
                     ?>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
                <select name="locality_name" id="locality_name" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Locality</option>

        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
        </div>


            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6">
            </div>

             <div class="col-lg-5" id='TextBoxesGroup'>


             </div>

                <!---Address-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $city_name = array();
    $city_id   = array();

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        array_push($city_id,$row[city_id]);
        array_push($city_name,$row[city_name]);
    }

    $count = count($city_id);
```

Now you got city_id and city_name in different array.
Now loop through them in javascript.

```
    <script>

    var city_id = '<?php echo json_encode($city_id ); ?>';
    var city_name = '<?php echo json_encode($city_id ); ?>';

    var count = '<?php echo $count; ?>'

     for(var k=0;k<count;k++){

         //  Add options here.
     }
    </script>
```